# How to display the oldest date for a unique user who has multiple dates in a database?

Tags: sql, soql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Let's say that my output looks like this (simplified example):

| UserName | ProfileCreation | PurchasePrice | PurchaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Dec 21 2019 6:00AM | 120.00 | Dec 21 2019 8:00AM |
| Alice | Dec 21 2019 6:00AM | 90.00 | Dec 25 2019 9:00AM |
| Alice | Dec 21 2019 6:00AM | 150.00 | Jan 02 2020 10:00AM |
| Bob | Jan 01 2020 9:00PM | 50.00 | Jan 03 2020 11:00PM |
| Bob | Jan 01 2020 9:00PM | 70.00 | Jan 07 2020 11:00PM |

The code for this output would look like this, I guess (not that important):

```
SELECT
UserName, ProfileCreation, PurchasePrice, PurchaseDate
FROM Some_Random_Database
```

But my desired output should look like this:

| UserName | ProfileCreation | PurchasePrice | FirstPurchaseDate | NumberOfPurchases | AvgOfPurchasePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Dec 21 2019 | 120.00 | Dec 21 2019 | 3 | 120.00 |
| Bob | Jan 01 2020 | 50.00 | Jan 03 2020 | 2 | 60.00 |

Hopefully, it's understandable what my goal is - to have unique user with date of his/her oldest purchase and with some calculated metrics for all purchases. Price of the first purchase can stay, but it is not necessary.

I'm writing in SOQL dialect - Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Obviously, I've got some ideas how to do some of the intended tweaks in my code, but I'd like to see a solution from any expert who is willing to show me the best way possible. I'm really just a noob :-)

I appreciate any help, guys!

Comment: WHat have you tried so far? Do you know aggregation functions?

Comment: Yeah. SUM() and AVG() combined with GROUP BY. I also know about CONVERT(DATE, TIMESTAMP) to cut off the time part of the timestamp. But I really don't know how to display only the first (or the last) of those purchase dates...

Comment: Super! What about window functions: `MAX(fieldname) OVER(ORDER BY datefield)` or `MIN(fieldname) OVER(ORDER BY datefield)`?

Comment: Never seen that before, but it seems legit. It might work somehow, even when I don't know how exactly...yet :-)

Comment: The best way to teach yourself is to trying and trying, and trying  ;)

Comment: Yeah, definitely. I'll let you know if I figured it out. Thanks so far!

Comment: Okay, I must admit I'm helpless with this. Not sure which variable put instead of "datefield".

Comment: Take a look here: [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d841b88e7df882ed0977ee7871b952c8)

Comment: Looks promising! But it's not correct. Row for Alice is okay, but Bob is calculated together with her. Thanks anyway! And by the way, the second solution you just posted (PARTITION) looks much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: i know nothing about Salesforce Marketing Cloud, but...

There's few ways to achieve that:

#1 - standard sql

```
SELECT UserName, ProfileCreation
  , MIN(PurchaseDate) FirstPurchaseDate
  , COUNT(PurchasePrice) NoOfPurchases
  , AVG(PurchasePrice) AvgPurchasePrice
FROM Foo
GROUP BY UserName, ProfileCreation;
```

#2 - window functions

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserName, ProfileCreation
  , MIN(PurchaseDate) OVER(PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY UserName) FirstPurchaseDate
  , COUNT(PurchasePrice) OVER(PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY UserName) NoOfPurchases
  , AVG(PurchasePrice) OVER(PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY UserName) AvgPurchasePrice
FROM Foo;
```

Comment: Only the second solution looks correct to me. Based on my tries.

Comment: But thank you so much! This definitely helped a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome. If, it's helpful, then please, accept my answer as a solution.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT
UserName, ProfileCreation, PurchasePrice, PurchaseDate
FROM
Some_Random_Database
WHERE
(UserName, PurchaseDate)  IN
(SELECT UserName, max(PurchaseDate) FROM Some_Random_Database GROUP BY UserName);

Comment: This does not show the FirstPurchaseDate, number of purchases, etc as requested.  It only limits the output to one row per username.  GROUP BY would be needed in this answer, along with some other details, and the WHERE clause should be removed.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but thank you anyway. It is inspiring. I did not know you can do this WHERE on a subset of columns.